# Sql server ignoring numerator as per denominator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the following format :

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4
abc         345    56        67
abc          43    56        87
abc         54     34        12 
abc         null   12        56

select Column1,sum(Column2+Column3)/sum(Column4 +Columnn3) as pct
group by column1
```

which gives me 600/380=1.57 but 
I want to ignore summation of Column 4 + column3 when Column 2 is null so the output should be 588/312=1.88

Can someone let me know how can i ignore the denominator if the one of the value in the  numerator is null

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the `213` from?

Comment: sorry made the change

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can use `isnull` to use an alternative value for `null`:

```
select  col1
,       sum(isnull(col2, 0) + col3) / sum(col4 + col3)
from    YourTable
group by
        col1
```

**EDIT** In response to your comment, check out JChao's answer.

Comment: but this will still include the last row in the calculation of the numertor ,i want to ignore the numerator and denominator in the calculation if column 2 is null

Comment: Math: `SUM(a)/SUM(b)` is ***not*** the same as `SUM(a/b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just filter out the null row?

```
    select Column1,sum(Column2+Column3)/sum(Column4 +Column3) as pct
    from table1 
    where column2 is not null
    group by column1
```